# Changing alpha value of objects in an NSArray iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, sdk, nsarray

OK so I thought this would be pretty simple but it's tripping me up.. I'm sure i'm just missing something simple, but could you guys help me out? Im trying to change the alpha values of objects (uiimageviews) in an nsarray. So far i got:

```
for (int i=1; i < [alphaSet count]; i++) {
   [[alphaSet objectAtIndex:i] setAlpha:masterAlpha];
}
```

It just throws bad access... Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the array `alphaSet` is allocated by using `alloc` before you filled it with data? The error says that you are reaching out of bounds of the array and this could be a reason for it since if it is not allocated you won't have any item in it and you will have bad access.

Comment: Any particular reason you're skipping the first object in your array? (i.e. object at index 0)

Comment: Naming suggestion: "alphaSet" sounds like an instance of `NSSet`, not `NSArray`. I'd suggest `alphaViews` here or `alphaList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSLog` to make sure your image views are there.

```
for (int i=1; i < [alphaSet count]; i++) {
   NSLog(@"At count %i there is this object: %@", i, [alphaSet objectAtIndex:i]);
   UIImageView *iv = [alphaSet objectAtIndex:i];
   iv.alpha = masterAlpha;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not sure why you're skipping the first index. Assuming this is a mistake, check your code and verify that it matches up with the following:

**NSArrayDeclaration**

```
NSArray * alphaSet;
//Your code for objects
```

**masterAlpha Declaration**

```
float masterAlpha = 0.5; //Whatever value you have
```

**Alpha Change**

```
for (int i = 0; i < [alphaSet count]; i++) {
    UIImageView * imageView = [alphaSet objectAtIndex:i];
    imageView.alpha = masterAlpha;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd wager that the array is empty.  A typical for-loop from 0..[array count] would fail to run harmlessly, but counting from index=1 on an empty array is a "bad access" crash.

So the code that needs looking at is the code where you initialize the alphaSet.  Meanwhile, a better way to enumerate it is like this:

```
for (UIImageView *imageView in alphaSet) {
  imageView.alpha = masterAlpha;
}
```

This is faster, easier on the eyes, and it will never crash on array bounds.  But you won't get any effect in the UI until you find out why alphaSet is empty.

Answer (score 1):

It's much safer and also faster to use fast enumeration

Instead if

```
for (int i = 0; i < [alphaSet count]; i++) {
    // do work
}
```

Use

```
for (UIImageView *imageView in alphaSet) {
    // do work
}
```

This removes the chances of off by one errors and incorrect initialisation like in your example.

---

For this example as you are only doing one thing you do not need to set up the for loop at all and can instead use

```
[alphaSet setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:masterAlpha] forKey:@"alpha"];
```